# Apache in Xampp keeps crashing on start

Tags: apache, xampp

I have installed Xampp as I need an Apache server set up but even though I've tried everything over and over, the thing still crashed whenever I start it up. I've made sure the ports are open, I'm in administrator mode and I even made sure to install the VC packages from 2008 - 2017.

MySQL works but Apache doesn't. I click on start and it gives me this error:

```
22:23:35  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
22:23:35  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
22:23:35  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another 
method.
22:23:35  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
22:23:35  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
22:23:35  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
22:23:35  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

I've tried asking on the Apache forums but they are of no use. Other error messages I got through other means are:

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.28.0, time stamp: 
0x59d4a9ab
Faulting module name: mod_version.so, version: 2.4.28.0, time stamp: 
0x59d4a9b0
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000870
Faulting process id: 0x15a0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3586ed92e5787
Faulting application path: c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\xampp\apache\modules\mod_version.so
Report Id: 18c711d5-c462-11e7-84f0-cb55049d9b8a

[Wed Nov 08 13:15:51.674477 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 3700:tid 396] AH01887: 
Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Wed Nov 08 13:15:51.676477 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 3700:tid 396] AH01914: 
Configuring server www.example.com:443 for SSL protocol
[Wed Nov 08 13:15:51.676477 2017] [ssl:debug] [pid 3700:tid 396] 
ssl_engine_init.c(444): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Wed Nov 08 13:15:51.677477 2017] [ssl:debug] [pid 3700:tid 396] 
ssl_util_ssl.c(443): AH02412: [www.example.com:443] Cert does not match for 
name 'www.example.com' [subject: CN=localhost / issuer: CN=localhost / 
serial: 
B5C752C98781B503 / notbefore: Nov 10 23:48:47 2009 GMT / notafter: Nov 8 
23:48:47 2019 GMT]
[Wed Nov 08 13:15:51.677477 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3700:tid 396] AH01909: 
www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which 
matches the server name
[Wed Nov 08 13:15:51.677477 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 3700:tid 396] AH02568: 
Certificate and private key www.example.com:443:0 configured from 
C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt and 
C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key
[Wed Nov 08 13:15:51.677477 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 3700:tid 396] AH01876: 
mod_ssl/2.4.28 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.28, Library: 
OpenSSL/1.0.2l
```

I've fixed all my DLL files and yet it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your Certificate doesn't match the `servername` you configured.  That's not a php or a mysql question, it's an `Apache` one.  You should have to look at your `httpd.conf` or your `ssl.conf` file.

Comment: I haven't set a server name or have a certificate yet because Apache crashes instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fixed this error!

I simply tried a really old version of XAMPP and it worked! It's so stupid how the new versions are more buggy than the old versions and that the people developing the thing can't even debug using their own debug messages.

I think I tried that old version before and it didn't work so it must have been something to do with the VC files.

Comment: It is probably best not to sound off about open source developers in public - it does not achieve anything, and may well be just plain wrong. We don't know if the problem is their fault or yours - my guess is that there's something on your machine that is upsetting the Windows executable. If you believe you have a reproducible problem, then log a bug with the team, and help them to fix it. That's the _quid pro quo_ of your getting quality software free of charge.